# After upgrading from 0.57.8 to 0.59.10 android crashes when invoking Alert.alert(...) with 'No virtual method isStateSaved()...'

Tags: android, gradle, apk, react-native, android-support-library

After we have upgraded react native from 0.57.8 to 0.59.10 we get a crash on android when we try to invoke an Alert.

Like:

```js
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
...
componentDidMount() {
// following line will crash on android only
 Alert.alert('Did mount', 'Your component has mounted!');
}
```

I have followed the upgrade path
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.57.8&to=0.59.10

This is the error I get from 
`android studio debug log:`

```sh
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.debitoor.android, PID: 4837
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method isStateSaved()Z in class Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager' appears in /data/app/com.debitoor.android-_akDnIP_mfHNd_jFi1g9WA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule$FragmentManagerHelper.showNewAlert(DialogModule.java:132)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule$1.run(DialogModule.java:258)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)


    --------- beginning of system
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4837 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

---

`android/app/build.gradle:`

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    flavorDimensions "debitoorApi", "test", "devMode"

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    }
    else {
        versionProps['VERSION_CODE']='0'
    }

    def code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.debitoor.android"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode code
        versionName "5.4.4"
        missingDimensionStrategy "minReactNative", "minReactNative46" // required for detox test
        testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug') // required for detox test
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" // required for detox test
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        local {
          ...
        }
        staging {
           ...
        }
        production {
          ...
        }
        noTest {
           ...
        }
        devModeOn {
            ...
        }
        devModeOff {
           ...
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
        resolutionStrategy {
           force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
           force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
           force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':@debitoor_react-native-sumup')
    implementation project(':react-native-cookies')
    implementation project(':react-native-document-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-branch')
    implementation project(':react-native-touch-id')
    implementation project(':react-native-pdf')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-open-settings')
    implementation project(':react-native-share')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation project(':react-native-build-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-logentries')
    implementation project(':react-native-intercom')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0") {
        force = true;
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-print')
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation project(':react-native-locale')
    implementation project(':react-native-mixpanel')
    implementation project(':react-native-fabric')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.10'
    // required for detox test
    androidTestImplementation(project(path: ":detox")) 
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'


    // Firebase
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


---
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.10' // Your app's version
    ext.detoxKotlinVersion = ext.kotlinVersion // Detox' version: should be 1.1.0 or higher!
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
        maven {
          url "https://jitpack.io"
        }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.sumup.com/releases'
        }
    }
}
```

---

And finally our list of dependencies:

```
    "bignumber.js": "4.0.0",
    "dateformat": "2.0.0",
    "deep-equal": "1.0.1",
    "dot-prop-immutable": "1.3.1",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "fbjs": "0.8.16",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "murmurhash": "0.0.2",
    "prop-types": "15.6.0",
    "query-string": "4.3.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "15.6.2",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-branch": "2.3.0",
    "react-native-build-config": "github:ismaeldcom/react-native-build-config#fb4e89e",
    "react-native-camera": "2.11.0",
    "react-native-communications": "2.2.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "2.2.0",
    "react-native-cookies": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "2.3.2",
    "react-native-dismiss-keyboard": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "git+ssh://git@github.com:debitoor/react-native-document-picker.git#0283de71ad3823125abb8ff66dbc916cf6ca914d",
    "react-native-env": "git+ssh://git@github.com/debitoor/react-native-env.git#c5a1e2b",
    "react-native-fabric": "0.5.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "0.10.1",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.2.3",
    "react-native-firebase-analytics": "3.0.5",
    "react-native-fs": "2.10.14",
    "react-native-image-picker": "github:debitoor/react-native-image-picker#54555a4",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "2.2.13",
    "react-native-in-app-utils": "git+ssh://git@github.com/debitoor/react-native-in-app-utils.git#9f1f3bf",
    "react-native-intercom": "10.2.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-locale": "0.0.18",
    "react-native-logentries": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-map-link": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "0.8.0",
    "react-native-mixpanel": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "git+ssh://git@github.com/debitoor/react-native-navigation#modalfix",
    "react-native-open-settings": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-orientation": "3.1.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "3.0.8",
    "react-native-permissions": "1.0.6",
    "react-native-print": "git+https://github.com/debitoor/react-native-print.git#74f776e",
    "react-native-push-notification": "3.0.2",
    "react-native-quick-actions": "0.2.1",
    "react-native-search-api": "git+ssh://git@github.com/gundlev/react-native-search-api.git#ffa18bb",
    "react-native-share": "1.0.27",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "3.7.5",
    "react-native-swipeout": "2.3.1",
    "react-native-touch-id": "4.0.4",
    "react-native-user-avatar": "1.0.3",
    "react-native-userdefaults-ios": "git+ssh://git@github.com/debitoor/react-native-userdefaults-ios.git#3a62243",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.5.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-debounced": "0.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.2",
    "redux-logger": "2.8.1",
    "redux-persist": "4.4.0",
    "redux-persist-filesystem-storage": "1.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "safe-json-stringify": "1.2.0",
    "throttle-debounce": "1.0.1",
    "traverse": "0.6.6",
    "util": "0.10.3",
    "uuid": "3.0.1"
```

From the error message `com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule` it could look like we are missing a sdk or havn't upgraded correctly. But i just can't pinpoint it.
I have tried

- clean: `rm -rf node_modules && ./scripts/clean-build-cache.sh && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` and then `yarn install` again...
- clean in android studio rebuild
- restarting computer, studio, simulators, terminals
- building on simulators with api level 26 and 28

Answer (score 0):

After updating to 0.59 it was common to get issues in Native modules like Alert,Toast,DatePickerAndroid etc.
I got a similar issue with ToastAndroid("my messsage") and found that it was because of missing second argument 'duration'. But it was working without 'duration' in prior versions.

So providing the complete arguments will work.

```
 Alert.alert('Did mount', 'Your component has mounted!',
          [
            {
              text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
                console.log('OK Pressed')
              }
            },
          ],
          { cancelable: true },
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried you solution, but it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in our resolution strategy. After removing

```
 resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
```

it worked again